# Perl-Mechanize posting hidden form value

Tags: perl, mechanize, hidden-field

I am attempting to create a perl script to test a web form for me. I am using mechanize for the automation and am having trouble finding documentation on the the field method. I am using the field method to return the value of a hidden form and this is causing my post to fail. The problem is probably a simple oversight but I am curious about `$mech->field('name');` as it seems to be returning the hidden form's value for me.

`Using perl v5.16.3` (w & w/o warnings)

```
$id = $test->field('MId');  
print $id . " \n"; 
          #This is printing the desired Id ,
          #the post will  not succeed as long as $id assigned this way. 

print "This is where I am attempting to upload the images\n";
my $fileuploadresult;
$fileuploadresult = $mech->post($uploadURL,
    'Content_Type' => "multipart/form-data",
    'Content' => [
    'myFile' => $file , 'MId' => $id
    ]
    );
print $fileuploadresult->content() . "\n\n\n"; #If I set $id to something like 'test' it
#will work fine.
#I am using two agent because there are two POST's going on and they have to be sequential.
```

I was wondering why my submit failed when I grabbed the value of a form. I just changed the 'field' method to 'value' and realized this fixed my problem. Sorry noob question didn't look at the documentation enough. When field returned the value I assumed that was part of its functionality I did not realize it also set the value to null. (Or as far as I can tell that is what its doing)

Comment: What's your question exactly?